# El tipo MySqlConnection No esta definido

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim conexion As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            conexion.Server = "localhost"
            conexion.UserID = "root"
            conexion.Password = ""
            conexion.Database = ".net"
            Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conexion.ToString())
            con.Open()
            MsgBox("Conexion Establecida")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("No se Pudo establecer la conexion" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregue la referencia,despues de instalar y demas pero me sigue diciendo que no esta definido.. Ayuda

Comment: Lo que se ve es que te falta instalar el connector de mysql server para visual studio

Comment: Hola Jeronimo, por favor dale a [edit] la pregunta y pon tu código y mensaje de error en modo texto en lugar de como una imagen. Tal y como están ahora en la pregunta no se pueden buscar y son más difíciles de leer. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Como te dije instale el connector y le agregue la referencia pero me sigue haciendo eso.

Comment: Hola ya intentaste crear una conexión normal de strings desde la app.config

Answer (score 1):

acabo de hacer una prueba en mi entorno instalandome el mysql desde cero https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474803 y funciono OK. Adjunto evidencia para que verifiques la configuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]